# get element by ID and change style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JQuery that is working fine, it grabs the user input, performs a calculation, then spits the result out. I need some assistance on then using getElementByID to compare the two results from the JQuery which is has spit out into the ID elements, and if one result is less than the second result, change elementByID to colour e.g. red.

if plan costs (total) is < than totalTP (tax deductible field) then do colour change

See the JSFiddle of my attempt

https://jsfiddle.net/p3smeb4u/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this will run on every select value change. if you want it to only run for those specific selects, add the same class in all of them and change the selector to $('select.yourclass')
  $('select').on('change', function() {

     total = Number($('.first').val()) + Number($('.second').val()) + Number($('.third').val())

     var calc = total / 19 * 100;

     var newNum = calc.toFixed(2);

   $('#total').text('£' + newNum);



  });

});



$(document).ready(function() {
$("#qty").keyup(function(){
   totalTP = $("#qty").val()* $("#price").val() / 100;
   $("#totalTP").val(totalTP);

   var myElement = document.getElementById("totalTP");
var myElement2 = document.getElementById("total");

function colorChange() {
  if (myElement2.innerHTML < myElement.innerHTML) {

    total.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    total.style.color = 'green';
  }
}

});

});
```

Comment: with jQuery you don't need to do `getElementById` you may use `$('#yourIdGoesHere')` type of syntax to select desired element and `.addClass()` method to apply necessary class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially as Tom mention, since you are already using JQuery, take advantage of that using the `.css` method like this:

```
const getNewNum = () => {
  const total =
    Number($(".first").val()) +
    Number($(".second").val()) +
    Number($(".third").val());

  const calc = (total / 19) * 100;
  return calc.toFixed(2);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    const newNum = getNewNum();
    $("#total").text("£" + newNum);
  });

  $("#qty").keyup(function() {
    const totalTP = ($("#qty").val() * $("#price").val()) / 100;

    $("#totalTP").val(totalTP);

    const newNum = getNewNum();

    const color = parseFloat(newNum) > totalTP ? "red" : "green"
    $("#total").css("color", color);
  });
});
```

here is the example working properly:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xozLyef4/1/
```

hope this help :)

Comment: the issue is, the user can add select from drop downs which changes the plan cost, so we need it to constantly check for the correct font colour to apply

Answer (score 0):

Try this my dear, you can use "css" jquery method to handle the style.

```
  $('#total').text('£' + newNum);

  // Just add this code snippet
  var totalTp = $("#totalTP").val();
  if(parseInt(newNum) < parseInt(totalTp)){
     $("#total").css("color", "green");
  }else{
     $("#total").css("color", "red");
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, it does, but then if you test the updated JSFiddle, it dosn't fully work,

Comment: I edited the answer, just add the code snippet after   $('#total').text('£' + newNum); try this and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Unless I don't quite understand your objective ... you intend to change the color of Plan Costs when it is less than the Deducitble Tax Available,that's right?

Comment: when plan costs is < than Deducitble Tax Available then plan costs colour is green if not, its red

Comment: if you look at code snippet, input 10000 in the first top box, then play around with some of the drop downs...youll see

Comment: Ah, you need to set the input to type = "number"  : <input name="totalTP" id="totalTP" type="number" />

Comment: you are welcome :) let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: sorry, still, check my js fiddle dosnt check properly, https://jsfiddle.net/p3smeb4u/7/

Comment: soon as you select an item from dropdwon, it goes red, even when clearly, the value is less than totalTP

Comment: I edited the answer again ... this time with parseInt, can you try again? the variables were like strings, so the calculation was not being done correctly .. I ended up forgetting that.. I believe that parseInt already solves :)